# HttpSelfHostServer not recognizing "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with an HttpSelfHostServer in .Net 4.5 and it seems to only be able to determine the controller and action when I send a request using QueryString. It doesn't work if I use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Here's the HttpSelfHostServer code.

```
private static HttpSelfHostConfiguration _config;
private static HttpSelfHostServer _server;
public static readonly string SelfHostUrl = "http://localhost:8989";

internal static void Start()
{
    _config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(SelfHostUrl);
    _config.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact;
    _config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "API Default",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraints: null);

    _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(_config);

    _server.OpenAsync().Wait();
}
```

The controller code.

```
public class SettingsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Test(bool work)
    {
        return work;
    }
}
```

Here is the response I get when attempting to access it via REST Console using

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8989/api/Settings/Test
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:9
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost:8989
Origin:chrome-extension://cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
           (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview parsed
work=true
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:205
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 23 Dec 2013 22:41:10 GMT
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

So, if I change my request to a post to the url below, it works.

```
http://localhost:8989/api/Settings/Test?work=true
```

Why isn't Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action method parameter is `bool`, which is a simple type. By default, ASP.NET Web API populates it from URI path or query string. That is the reason `http://localhost:8989/api/Settings/Test?work=true` works.

When you send the same in the request body, it does not work because ASP.NET Web API binds body to a complex type (class) by default and hence the body will not be bound to your argument type `bool`. To ask Web API to bind the simple type from body, change your action method like this.

`public bool Test([FromBody]bool work)`

Then, you will need to send only the value in the body, like this.

`=true`.

Comment: The example you show works. Also the description of making a complex type (class) works for if I wanted to specify Work = true. Your description also helps me to understand a little more how the ASP.NET Web API binding works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the Content-Type.  The rest console uses AJAX and CORS, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing.  This is indicated by the `Origin` http header in the request.

The server that contains the `SettingsController` must support CORS.  If it doesn't the AJAX request will always return a 404.

The easiest way for you to support CORS is to always return a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the request HTTP headers.

Comment: Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * did not fix the issue. Although, I had actually used that earlier in this project when attempting to access the API through an html file run locally. I removed it when I no longer had to access the html files from file:/// and created a custom handler to host them along side the API. Thank you for the answer.